# Find a specific number in the middle of a string and remove it from list of numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net

I don't have much code to show but I am trying to remove a substring (individual number) from a longer string is a series of numbers.

> Ex: Main String is "11,12,15,16,55,33,88,100,121,155,115"

Need to find number 16 and remove it from the string leaving...

> 11,12,15,55,33,88,100,121,155,115

They are a list of id's from a database so I can't just change them to strings.  Also how do I remove it as if it wasn't there?

Comment: Do you want to remove all occurences of 16 from the string? Why don't you use a `List<int>` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string numbers = "11,12,15,16,55,33,88,100,121,155,115";
numbers = string.Join(",", numbers.Split(',').Where(num => num != "16"));
```

But why don't you use a `List<int>` instead for database  ID's?

Answer (score 1):

In this specific use case I would split the string using "," as the separator, remove the element that matches, then join the elements again.